# BLAS/LAPACK subroutine to add two matrices with different offsets and leading dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, lapack, blas

I currently searching for a subroutine from BLAS or LAPACK which realizes the following operation

```
A = alpha*A + beta * B
```

where A and B have different leading dimensions, i.e. A is stored as

```
 REAL*8 A(N,N)
```

and B is stored as

```
 REAL*B B(LDB,N)
```

with LDB > N.

Is there a way to use existing BLAS or LAPACK operation to compute this or must I create an own subroutine for this kind of problems?

Comment: What does it mean to add two matrices with different dimensions?

Comment: It is only the leading dimension, the means the length of a column in the Fortran storage format, i.e. the in memory distance between two elements of the same row

Comment: I'm aware that Fortran stores 2D arrays in column major order.  Wouldn't the question be clearer if `A = alpha*A + beta * B` were replaced by the nested do-loop that tells which expressions are to be added to assign `A(I,J)`?

Comment: Replacing this by a nested do-loop or the quick-and-dirty Fortran-code which does the same job, does not help understanding the problem. The leading dimension problem can be handle by Fortran directly so the code does not point out the problem. Currently I use such a code but I'm interested if there is a efficient way using the standard linalg libraries.

Comment: I'm suggesting the nested do-loop not as a solution, but as a meaningful way to phrase the *question*.  `A = alpha*A + beta * B` doesn't convey what you mean, though I'm sure the meaning is so clear in your mind you have difficulty seeing that it becomes a guessing game for me.

Comment: Grisu, I agree with hardmath. Please clarify what you mean in your question so that users are better able to help you.

Comment: I think this warrants an explanation of what 'leading dimension' means, and the fact that BLAS allows you to have 'leading dimension' larger than the matrix dimension (this means there is extra data, not touched by BLAS, in between columns). It's clear to me, but I can see how it can be confusing to somebody not familiar with BLAS/LAPACK.

Answer (score 3):

Just write the loop code and forget about BLAS here.  Adding two matrices is bandwidth-limited and the compiler will likely do as good a job as the BLAS implementation *in this case*.

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do is to use the BLAS `AXPY` on each column, but that doesn't let you apply `beta`. You really might as well write your own since this is basically a level 1 or 2 BLAS operation, which for large matrices is memory bandwidth limited.